# O que exatamente git checkout branch -- . faz?

Tags: git

Gostaria de entender este comando de uma forma mais fácil, fiz alguns testes mas não estou muito seguro da conclusão. Tenho dois branches, o branch master e o branch novo, e fiz o teste descrito a seguir.

Diretório no último commit do brach master:

```
Arquivo    Conteúdo
a.txt      Arquivo a.txt do branch master
b.txt      Arquivo b.txt do branch master
```

Diretório no último commit do branch novo:

```
Arquivo    Conteúdo
a.txt      Arquivo a.txt do branch novo
c.txt      Arquivo c.txt do branch novo
```

Git status:

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Executando o comando

```
$ git checkout novo -- .
```

O diretório ficou:

```
Arquivo    Conteúdo
a.txt      Arquivo a.txt do branch novo
b.txt      Arquivo b.txt do branch master
c.txt      Arquivo c.txt do branch novo
```

Git status:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   a.txt
    new file:   c.txt
```

Pra mim parece que ele está pegando todos os arquivos do branch novo, copiando e colando em cima do diretório de trabalho, sobre-escrevendo todos os arquivos com o mesmo nome. É isso mesmo, posso contar com esse comportamento? Tem como o git sobre-escrever um arquivo de nome diferente?

Note que o comando git checkout possui comportamento diferente dependendo dos parâmetros. Estou perguntando especificamente da versão do comando que possui algum arquivo como parâmetro. No comando que eu mencionei, o ponto está especificando o diretório atual (que no caso contém todos os arquivos) e faz diferença no comportamento do comando. Repare nos dois git status que o comando não muda de branch como o checkout sem "-- .".

Comment: Esse comando está estranho. Acho que o comportamento dele é: Jogue fora todas as modificações/delete na branch atual e copie os arquivos da arvore "novo" para a branch master. O que exatamente você está querendo fazer?

Comment: Inicialmente eu também achei que era isso! Dai fiz o seguinte teste: modifiquei o arquivo b.txt, usei o comando e a modificação do arquivo continuou no diretório de trabalho. Então ele não joga fora as modificações/delete, parece que apenas copia os arquivos.

Comment: Usei esse comando e dei commit em um projeto e obtive um resultado bem estranho, não sei se foi por causa desse ou de algum outro comando. Agora quero entender perfeitamente pra não acontecer o mesmo problema. O que eu queria mesmo saber é se em alguma ocasião o git pode identificar que um arquivo foi renomeado ou algo assim e sobre-escrever nele mesmo com nome diferente. Mas obrigado, foi uma boa opinião =)

Comment: Só pra constar, a partir do Git 2.23 (de 2019) foi criado o `git restore`, então o comando equivalente seria `git restore --source=novo --staged --worktree .`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

O `git checkout branch` pode ser usado nas seguintes situações:

1 - Mudar de branch.
Quando o git muda de branch, todas as alterações que foram aplicadas na branch serão substituídas pelas alterações da branch que foi feito o checkout.

Ao criar um repositório git, o repositório já começa com uma branch chamada de master. Imagine que nesse momento você cria um arquivo master.txt e faz o commit desse arquivo. Em seguida você cria uma nova branch chamada nova-branch, essa nova branch, nesse momento, possuirá o mesmo conteúdo da branch master. Portanto, quanto você executar o comando `git checkout nova-branch`, nenhuma diferença será notada.

Imagine agora que você cria um novo arquivo chamado nova-branch.txt e faz o commit desse arquivo. Nesse momento haverão dois arquivos: o master.txt e o nova-branch.txt. Quando você executar o comando `git checkout master`, o seu working directory irá voltar para o estado em que a branch master está apontando, ou seja, o arquivo nova-branch.txt irá sumir, porque na branch master esse arquivo não existe.

Imagine agora que você cria um arquivo chamado novo-arquivo.txt e não comita esse arquivo. No diretório atual estão presentes os arquivos novo-arquivo.txt e master.txt. Em seguida você executa o comando `git checkout nova-branch`. O working directory irá voltar para o estado em que a nova-branch está apontando, ou seja, o arquivo nova-branch.txt irá aparecer. Contudo, o arquivo novo-arquivo.txt irá continuar aparecendo, isso porque esse arquivo não foi comitado, então ele não faz parte da branch master. Ele está no que é chamado de working copy, que são os arquivos que foram modificados, criados ou deletados, mas que não foram comitados. Esses arquivos vão continuar no working copy mesmo você alterando de branch. Dessa forma, se você quiser, poderá comitar esses arquivos na branch que desejar.

Os exemplos que eu dei foram em cima de criação de arquivos, mas claro que o mesmo se aplica se forem feitas alterações no arquivo.

2 - O git checkout pode ser usado para criar uma nova branch também. Se o comando for executado dessa forma: `git checkout -b nome-branch`. A branch será criada e em seguida o checkout será feito.

3 - O git checkout pode ser usado para criar localmente uma branch remota. Se você fizer o clone de algum repositório, será criado localmente somente    a branch master. Se você desejar trabalhar em cima de outra branch, basta executar o comando `git checkout nova-branch`, e a branch será criada localmente.

Um comando legal que você pode testar é esse: `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`.

O comando `git log` irá mostrar o histórico dos commits. Colocando o `--decorate` você irá ver para qual commit cada branch está apontando. O `--oneline` irá mostrar somente uma linha para cada commit para ficar mais fácil de visualisar. O `--graph` irá mostrar em quais pontos as branches bifurcaram e em quais pontos foram feitos merges. O `--all` irá mostrar o commit de todas as branches. Sem o `--all` somente os commits do HEAD serão mostrados, que no caso, são os commits da atual branch.

Além de mudar de branch, o git checkout pode ser usado para voltar um determinado arquivo para seu estado na staged area. A staged area são os arquivos que estão prontos para serem comitados. Em outras palavras, são os arquivos que executamos o comando `git add`. Se não há versão do arquivo na staged area, ele será retornado para a sua versão do último commit.
Imaginemos o seguinte cenário:

1. `echo algum texto > a.txt`
2. `git add a.txt`
3. `git commit -m 'adicionando a'`
4. `echo alterando texto de a > a.txt`

Nesse ponto, não desejamos comitar a alteração feita em a.txt. Queremos desfazer a alteração. Nesse caso, podemos usar o comando `git checkout a.txt`. As alterações feitas no arquivo serão descartadas.
Esse comando pode também ser usado das seguintes formas:

1. Para mais de um arquivo: `git checkout a.txt b.txt`
2. Para um diretório: `git checkout teste`

Podemos, no entanto, fazer um checkout para o arquivo em outra branch.

No exemplo que você deu o que aconteceu foi o seguinte:
Ao executar o comando `git checkout novo -- .` Foi feito o checkout de todos os arquivos do diretório atual que estão na branch novo. Nesse caso, os arquivos que existem na branch master e existem na branch novo, serão substituídos pela versão que está na branch novo. Os arquivos que apenas existem na branch novo serão adicionados na branch master.

O comportamento é similar se você estiver fazendo checkout dos arquivos na mesma branch. Imaginemos o seguinte cenário:

1. A branch master possui os seguintes arquivos comitados: a.txt e b.txt.
2. Você então remove o arquivo b.txt, altera o a.txt e cria o c.txt
3. Você então executa o comando `git checkout .`

Veja que o comportamento será o mesmo. O arquivo a.txt volta para o estado do último commit na branch novo, o arquivo b.txt volta a aparecer e o arquivo c.txt continua aparecendo, mas como untracked.

A diferença desses casos são:

1. `git checkout .` - Os arquivos do diretório atual serão retornados para suas versões na staged area. Se não houver versão na staged area, serão retornados para suas versões no último commit na branch.
2. `git checkout nome-branch .` - Os arquivos do diretório serão retornados para versão do último commit da branch desejada.

No caso de ser criado um novo arquivo e esse arquivo não ser comitado, quando for realizado o `git checkout .`, esse arquivo não irá sumir. Isso porque o git não tem conhecimento desse arquivo, porque ele ainda não foi versionado. Ele continuará no working copy como um arquivo untracked.

Do mesmo modo, se um arquivo apenas existe na branch master e não existe em outra branch, ao executar o comando `git checkout outra-branch`, esse arquivo não irá sumir, porque na outra branch o git não tem conhecimento desse arquivo, portanto ele não irá fazer nada com o mesmo.

Para fins de esclarecimento, o "." significa que será utilizado o atual diretório e não todos os arquivos. Se você estiver no diretório raiz coincidentemente serão utilizados todos os arquivos. Mas se você entrar em algum diretório e executar o comando com o ".", será feito o checkout em todos os arquivos desse último diretório.

> Tem como o git sobre-escrever um arquivo de nome diferente?

Não. O git só irá sobre-escrever arquivos com o mesmo nome.

Se for utilizado o comando `git mv` o git saberá que o arquivo foi renomeado. Se o arquivo for renomeado sem esse comando, o git identificará que houve a remoção do arquivo com o antigo nome e que houve a criação do arquivo com o novo nome. Ainda assim, após executar o `git add` para as duas operações, o git conseguirá identificar que houve um rename.
Se o arquivo for renomeado em uma determinada branch, ao fazer merge com outra branch que está com o arquivo com o nome antigo, o git saberá que se trata do mesmo arquivo e tentará fazer o merge. Contudo, o mesmo não se aplica se for utilizado o `git checkout`. O git não conseguirá fazer o checkout de um arquivo em outra branch se o arquivo não estiver com o mesmo nome. Exemplo:

1. `echo primeira linha > a.txt`
2. `git add a.txt`
3. `git commit -m 'adicionando arquivo a.txt'`
4. `git checkout novo`
5. `git merge master`
6. `git mv a.txt novoNome.txt`
7. `git commit -m 'alterando nome de a para novoNome'`
8. `git checkout master`

Nesse ponto, se for executado o comando `git checkout novo d.txt`, o git não irá encontrar esse arquivo na branch novo. Se for executado o comando `git checkout novo novoNome.txt`, o subsequente arquivo será trazido para a branch master mas não irá substituir o antigo d.txt.

Comment: Parabéns por essa explanação sucinta.